# USB devices connecting then disconnecting permanently on intermittent boots for Ubuntu 16.04 Raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, usb, raspberry-pi, udev, dmesg

Every so often (about 25% of the time) when I boot up my pi, the USB devices will not work. Looking at dmesg output below. It appears my devices connect, then disconnect a second or two later, and then once in the system TTYUSB0, TTYUSB1 and TTYUSB2 files are all missing as well. On a subsequent boot, the devices bind OK and everything works 100%, hence the intermittent nature of this problem.

This intermittent problem began arising after doing a system update and upgrade, as well as running the following commands. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

```
sudo -Es
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl disable --now ifupdown dhcpcd dhcpcd5 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common rsyslog
apt --autoremove purge ifupdown dhcpcd dhcpcd5 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common rsyslog
rm -r /etc/network /etc/dhcp
systemctl disable --now avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
apt --autoremove purge avahi-daemon
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
apt install libnss-resolve
ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
apt-mark hold avahi-daemon dhcpcd dhcpcd5 ifupdown isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libnss-mdns openresolv raspberrypi-net-mods rsyslog
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service
exit
```

---

```
[    4.004167] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    4.099090] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    4.108376] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with erro
[    4.108398] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    4.158111] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[    4.167330] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM43
[    4.167769] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.195837] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspber
[    4.376882] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM43
[    4.396739] rtc-ds1307: probe of 1-006f failed with error -121
[    4.398437] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Mar  1 2015 07:29:38
[    4.554898] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[    4.662995] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    4.663037] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    4.672106] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[    4.672120] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[    4.672160] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[    4.672206] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[    4.672316] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[    4.672318] cp210x 1-1.3:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[    4.672428] usb 1-1.2: Detected FT232RL
[    4.679334] usb 1-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    4.679537] ftdi_sio 1-1.4:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[    4.679646] usb 1-1.4: Detected FT232RL
[    4.682651] usb 1-1.3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    4.683305] usb 1-1.4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[    4.697841] rpivid-mem feb00000.hevc-decoder: rpivid-hevcmem initialised: Registers at 0xf
[    4.698166] rpivid-mem feb10000.rpivid-local-intc: rpivid-intcmem initialised: Registers a
[    4.698387] rpivid-mem feb20000.h264-decoder: rpivid-h264mem initialised: Registers at 0xf
[    4.699574] rpivid-mem feb30000.vp9-decoder: rpivid-vp9mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb
[    4.705043] bcmgenet: Skipping UMAC reset
[    4.706545] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII
[    4.706747] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[    4.960922] random: crng init done
[    4.960936] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[    6.113256] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[    6.113557] rp-usbdisp 1-1.1:1.0: waiting for all tickets to be finished...
[    6.113785] rp-usbdisp 1-1.1:1.0: RP USB Display (#1) now disconnected
[    6.115705] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[    6.116286] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUS
[    6.116345] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
[    6.117190] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[    6.117575] cp210x ttyUSB1: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[    6.117633] cp210x 1-1.3:1.0: device disconnected
[    6.118441] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
[    6.118994] ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUS
[    6.119050] ftdi_sio 1-1.4:1.0: device disconnected
[    7.463926] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    9.930297] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[    9.930327] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   10.867743] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Upda
[   10.871278] Bridge firewalling registered
[   11.261788] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   11.261933] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 65 at net/wireless/sme.c:756 __cfg80211_connect_result+0x
[   11.261938] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xt_addrtype iptable_filter iashfs overlay binfmt_misc rpivid_mem cp210x ftdi_sio usbserial rtc_ds1307 regmap_i2c brcmfmac_midi snd_seq_midi_event bcm2835_codec(C) v4l2_mem2mem videobuf2_dma_contig snd_rawmidi raspbuio evdev joydev bcm2835_v4l2(C) bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) vc_sm_cma(C) videobuf2_vmalloc videobuysimgblt fb_sys_fops ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6
[   11.262054] CPU: 1 PID: 65 Comm: kworker/u8:1 Tainted: G         C O      5.4.51-v7l+ #133
[   11.262057] Hardware name: BCM2711
[   11.262129] Workqueue: cfg80211 cfg80211_event_work [cfg80211]
[   11.262133] Backtrace:
[   11.262146] [<c020d46c>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c020d768>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[   11.262151]  r6:ef294000 r5:00000000 r4:c129c8f8 r3:ad07bc4f
[   11.262160] [<c020d748>] (show_stack) from [<c0a39a44>] (dump_stack+0xe0/0x124)
[   11.262169] [<c0a39964>] (dump_stack) from [<c0221c70>] (__warn+0xec/0x104)
[   11.262174]  r8:000002f4 r7:00000009 r6:bf28c168 r5:00000000 r4:00000000 r3:ad07bc4f
[   11.262180] [<c0221b84>] (__warn) from [<c0221d40>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0xb8/0xc0)
[   11.262185]  r9:bf28c168 r8:000002f4 r7:bf260d00 r6:00000009 r5:00000000 r4:c1204f88
[   11.262254] [<c0221c8c>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf260d00>] (__cfg80211_connect_result+
[   11.262259]  r9:00000122 r8:ef295e54 r7:c1204f88 r6:00000000 r5:dffa840c r4:dffc5004
[   11.262389] [<bf2608c4>] (__cfg80211_connect_result [cfg80211]) from [<bf22cb0c>] (cfg8021
[   11.262394]  r8:dffc5090 r7:dffc5028 r6:dffc5098 r5:dffc5004 r4:dffa8400
[   11.262523] [<bf22ca08>] (cfg80211_process_wdev_events [cfg80211]) from [<bf22cba8>] (cfg8
[   11.262529]  r10:00000000 r9:00000100 r8:00000000 r7:dfe17600 r6:ef846400 r5:df60c470
[   11.262532]  r4:dffc5004
[   11.262659] [<bf22cb68>] (cfg80211_process_rdev_events [cfg80211]) from [<bf2261b8>] (cfg8
[   11.262663]  r5:ef977100 r4:df60c0e4
[   11.262732] [<bf226194>] (cfg80211_event_work [cfg80211]) from [<c023e244>] (process_one_w
[   11.262736]  r4:df60c0e4 r3:bf226194
[   11.262742] [<c023e0c8>] (process_one_work) from [<c023eaac>] (worker_thread+0x54/0x5b4)
[   11.262747]  r10:ef977100 r9:ef294038 r8:c1203d00 r7:ef846418 r6:00000088 r5:ef977114
[   11.262751]  r4:ef846400
[   11.262757] [<c023ea58>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244e90>] (kthread+0x13c/0x168)
[   11.262762]  r10:efa174dc r9:ef901e74 r8:c023ea58 r7:ef977100 r6:00000000 r5:ef974200
[   11.262765]  r4:efa174c0
[   11.262771] [<c0244d54>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[   11.262775] Exception stack(0xef295fb0 to 0xef295ff8)
[   11.262779] 5fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   11.262784] 5fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   11.262789] 5fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[   11.262793]  r10:00000000 r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c0244d54
[   11.262797]  r4:ef974200 r3:c0204648
[   11.262814] ---[ end trace 18f9f282ca963cc4 ]---
[   11.483205] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
[   11.608570] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   30.602006] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   30.602064] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   30.602072] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   30.602091] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   30.602103] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   30.602122] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   30.609018] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   30.609029] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   30.609088] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   30.609284] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   30.694773] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   30.694783] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   30.694800] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  128.811552] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 38663. Sending cookies.
[  268.653076] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 39569. Sending cookies.
[  314.270766] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_vif_set_mgmt_ie: vndr ie set error : -52
[  314.271326] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_vif_set_mgmt_ie: vndr ie set error : -52
[  314.271935] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_vif_set_mgmt_ie: vndr ie set error : -52
[  315.693723] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 34855. Sending cookies.
[  501.855600] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 45579. Sending cookies.
ubuntu@subaero-CYEG-002:~$ ^C
ubuntu@subaero-CYEG-002:~$ dmesg | grep wpa
[   11.262180] [<c0221b84>] (__warn) from [<c0221d40>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0xb8/0xc0)
[   11.262254] [<c0221c8c>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf260d00>] (__cfg80211_connect_result+0x43c/0x4e8 [cfg80211])
[   11.483205] netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ifupdown and more specifically, disabling networking.service causes usb devices to disconnect after boot (not every time, about 25-50% of the time) and for the udev links to disappear.  Seems to be because networking.service is the only enabled service that runs udevadm settle on boot, thus deleting it can lead to instances of
udev being squashed on boot by other processes.

Creating an ‘execute once’ service that is enabled during boot and runs at the correct time is the fix for this issue when you want to disable networking.service and remove/purge ifupdown package.

Create a service called udevadm-settle-dummy.service in /lib/systemd/system

The service in the file above shall look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=run udevadm settle
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network.target
After=local-fs.target network-pre.target apparmor.service systemd-sysctl.servic$
Before=network.target shutdown.target network-online.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/sbin/udevadm settle
ExecStart=/sbin/udevadm settle
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStartSec=5min
```

Run the following commands in /lib/systemd/system:

```
sudo chmod 777 udevadm-settle-dummy.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable udevadm-settle-dummy.service
```